# JAVA: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, syntax

I'm using **Java + MySQL** for a game server project of mine. I'm having a problem though -

```
MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(connection) (`uuid`, `name`, `join_date`, `group`) VALUES (5dcd14f9 at line 1
```

The uuid should be 5dcd14f9-....-.....-...
Dots are characters that should exist there, and the dashes are just dashes.
For some reason I'm having a problem where it only gets the first part of the uuid.
Am I missing something, or is there actually something wrong with my syntax?
That's my code which is basically the error:

```
PreparedStatement addPlayer = mySQL.getConnection().prepareStatement("INSERT INTO " + mySQL.getConnection() + " (uuid, name, join_date, group) VALUES (?,?,?,?)");
```

I of course cast the uuid to a string and add it as a value to the first column.
I've looked at other solutions and tried them but they didn't seem to work.

Comment: Without seeing the code, it is rather hard to comment on a syntax error.

Comment: Seems like mySQL.getConnection() returns the value '(connection)'. You should have a table name anyway...

Comment: `mySQL.getConnection()` is wrong. It should be the TABLE name.

Comment: @jarlh and CoCoNess ty. I didn't even realize I put the connection and not table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your error I can see, that `mySQL.getConnection().toString()` produces the `"(connection)"`, which is not a valid syntax as the name of the table you're inserting into.

Maybe instead of:

```
PreparedStatement addPlayer = mySQL.getConnection().prepareStatement("INSERT INTO " + mySQL.getConnection() + " (uuid, name, join_date, group) VALUES (?,?,?,?)");
```

You wanted to write something like:

```
PreparedStatement addPlayer = mySQL.getConnection().prepareStatement("INSERT INTO " + getTableName() + " (uuid, name, join_date, group) VALUES (?,?,?,?)");
```

Comment: Nope I didn't case MySQL.getConnection() to a string, I just changed the address to (connection) to save space, my bad should've probably mentioned it

Comment: Doesn't mySQL.getTableName() need a parameter, to know which table name to return?

Comment: @Coper it happens automatically when you concatenate strings

Comment: @jarlh yeah, I rather meant any method, that returns a valid table name, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Yes, you're right my bad didn't realize I wrote the connection instead of table.